# .NET FtpWebRequest: How to check if file is ready to download

Tags: .net, download, ftpwebrequest

I have a service *.NET* using the *FtpWebRequest* to download images from an FTP server. I have a camera which stores images on the same FTP server.

If my service see an image and tries to download it before the camera has finished storing the same image, the 'not-yet-stored-part' of the image appears grey (corrupted).

**Question:** How do I detect whether the image is ready for download (stored completely)?

Comment: A dirty workaround would be to only download images which are older then x minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had control over the sending service, you would implement this using marker files. If the sending service would e.g. write a ".finished" file when it's done, you could wait for that file to appear.

However, I suspect you do not have control over the software in the camera. There are a few issues with detecting whether the camera has finished uploading, specifically with a slow internet connection.

I think the best solution would be to check for changes in file size. Monitor the folder and see whether new files appear. Then, if the file size has not changed for e.g. a minute, it should be fairly safe for you to download the file.

Comment: @**Pieter**: You are correct, I don't have control over the camera software. I will pursue the file size monitor idea - thanks for your answer =)

Answer (score 1):

Make the camera software store images in a different directory (let's call it Dir1). Try moving the files from this directory to another directory (let's call it Dir2).

If a file is still open by the camera software, the move should fail, so only completed images will be moved from Dir1 to Dir2.

Download images from Dir2.

Answer (score 0):

Upload another small file after the big file. Use the small file to check 'completeness' (or maybe an MD5 inside it would work too).